# Why does -webkit-text-stroke and many others not work in Edge but -webkit-text-fill-color does work on Edge?

Tags: css

I tried the prefix -ms- as somebody told me but I don't know if i'm doing it right, how do I make webkit-text-stroke work on Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this exact subject for you:

[Text stroke in Edge](https://exde601e.blogspot.com/2015/09/text-stroke-issues-in-microsoft-edge.html)

and here's some code for it:

```
 header h1 {
      color: white; text-align:center;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 3px white;
      /.*text-shadow: 0px 0px 0.1em aqua, 0px 0px 0.25em lime;*/
      font-size: 7em;
 }
 header h1:hover {
      -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
 }
```